# creating pagination for Magento CMS pages

Tags: magento, content-management-system

On the Magento Content Management Services CMS.
How can i create a simple pagination for the pages that i have? Whether it's Previous/Next or just numbering

I was able to do it with this

3
        3
        
            
        
        empty6
        one_column5
        two_columns_left4
        two_columns_right4
        three_columns3
        product_list_toolbar

getting 
[image]

But i don't want it for products, i want it for regular text, like blog.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to achieve.
In pure theory you can use pager block on any collection

(*untested*)

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();

$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'cms.page.pager')
            ->setCollection($collection);
$this->setChild('pager', $pager);

$collection->load();
```